# List items = new ArrayList() : it does not work

Tags: java, swing, list, arraylist, swingx

Is all in the title,
I do not understand the problem this time is a bit different, I used the same Object(List) for two different programs and it does not work in the second time, see :

```
private void jMenuItem23ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
init_creer_client();
List  items  = new ArrayList();
items.add("mawren");
items.add("blabla");
items.add("Bonjour");

CL.show(cartes,"creer_client");       
}
```

screenshot about the error :
[image]

by cons here its work smoothly :

```
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.HeadlessException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;
 import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator;

 public class Test_swingx extends JFrame {

public Test_swingx(String title) throws HeadlessException {

this.setTitle(title);
JPanel pan=new JPanel();
JTextField jtf=new JTextField();
jtf.setColumns(20);
List items  = new ArrayList();
items.add("hello");
items.add("marwen");
items.add("allooo");
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(jtf, items,false);
pan.add(jtf);
this.setContentPane(pan);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setBounds(280, 150, 500, 200);

}


 public static void main(String[] args) {

Test_swingx tsx=new Test_swingx("helloo swingx");

}
}
```

can anyone explain to me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a java.awt.List import should be java.util.List

Comment: Thanks solved,the most secure way its to use   java.util.List itmes=new ArrayList(); without import... Thanks for All.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the `List` on the left-hand side is a `java.awt.List` instead of a `java.util.List`.

Try changing the line to:

```
java.util.List items = new ArrayList();
```

This is probably happening because you're importing `java.awt.*` **and** `java.util.List`. If you can change how you import these classes, you can avoid namespacing the type inline.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, compiles fine:

```
package cruft;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * ListExample description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 2/11/12 7:27 PM
 */
public class ListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List items = new ArrayList();
        for (String arg : args) {
            items.add(arg);
        }
        System.out.println(items);
    }
}
```

Runs fine:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7536 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 111.255\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath . com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain cruft.ListExample foo bar baz bat
[foo, bar, baz, bat]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sanity check: Have you imported both `import java.util.List` and `import java.util.ArrayList`?

Comment: why List and ArrayList has to import seperately ? can i just import java.util.* ? tks inadvance ! :D

Comment: You can, but if you just want List and ArrayList there's little point in importing all of the other stuff in there when you're not going to use it :)

Comment: actually , if i wanna upcasting ArrayList to List , i have to do the import seperately . if not , it says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to List" , this error keeps showing until i import List and ArrayList Seperately ... tks for you reply !

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports, because `java.awt.List` is not the same as `java.util.List`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion comes from having two `List` types in different packages, as the error message says. You don't give all the code that generates the error, but I think a reasonable start to a fix would be to change the highlighted line to:

```
java.util.List items  = new ArrayList();
```

and make sure you have imported `java.util.*`

Comment: `s/java.lang.util/java.util/g` :)